# CakePHP 3 Error on using SplFileInfo class

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i'm getting the next error:
**Error: Class 'App\JL\SplFileInfo' not found**  while trying to create a SplFileInfo class like this: **$i = new SplFileInfo($P['Carpeta'].DS.$v);**
i tested this with same results: **$i = new SplFileInfo('');**
this is in a cutom class called JL in **namespace App\JL** and calling it like **use App\JL\JL;**

The function is declared like this: **public static function LeerArchivos(&$P = array()) {**

i'm working in an element to be shown on a template...

¿Do i have to activate somethig? or ¿What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't know how namespaces work. You should fix that gap in your knowledge first: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

You need to "import" the class from the "root" namespace `\` into your current namespace `\App\JL\JL`. This us done via the `use` keyword. [See the documentation for it.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Thank you, i used the "pathinfo" funtion insted and it worked successfully.